# Swift: DispatchQueue always Serial?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I receive a lot of data and want to process it off the main thread. Most of the things can be asynchronous in nature, however sometimes there is critical data coming in with each update invalidating the previous iteration. At the moment I set up everything like this:

```
func onReceivedData(d: Data){ //is on main thread unfortunately
    //some work 1
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {
        //some work 2
        if(saveToFile) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.utility).async {
                //UserDefaults write
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I am not sure if I understood the DispatchQueue correctly. Is it possible when data A comes in before data B, that data B for some reason may reach the `UserDefaults write` earlier than data A? Do the DispatchQueues push operations in a serial manner or can they also operate in parallel, potentially writing data B before data A, leaving the UserDefaults in an invalid state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Apple Developer documentation on `DispatchQueue.global()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global):

> Tasks submitted to the returned queue are scheduled concurrently with respect to one another.

This means that the `global()` queues are concurrent dispatch queues.
If you want to ensure that the tasks execute in the order that you schedule them, you should create your own serial `DispatchQueue`.

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my-queue")
queue.async {
    // Work 1...
}
queue.async {
    // Work 2...
}
```

"Work 1" will always run before "Work 2" in this serial queue (which may not be the case with a concurrent queue).

Alternatively, you could look into using a Swift `actor` which can more efficiently control access to shared mutable state in a memory-safe way.

Comment: Thank you for providing that information to me! Will the created `DispatchQueue` automatically ensure the work 1+2 will be executed on a background thread or will I have to wrap the `queue.async` calls in a way to avoid execution on the main thread?

Comment: @user2161301 When you create your own `DispatchQueue`, I don't believe the tasks are ever scheduled to run on the main thread (as they are designed for background work). You'll have to explicitly call `DispatchQueue.main` to get back to the main thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this!